# unable to create and delete on time. Works only when refreshed

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-httpclient

I'm building a crud operation and I'm able to do the operation. But it  get added and deleted only when i refresh. Otherwise it gives me an error.Am I missing something here? And why is it going to the catch operation while creating  and deleting and not when refreshing?

> ***service.ts***

```
 //create service

 sendRole(data){
 console.log(data);
 let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
 }).set('Authorization', 'Token ' + 
 localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));

 var options =  {
  headers: headers
 };
 return this.httpClient.post('api/auth/role/', data, this.options)
 .map((res:Response)=> res.json())
 .catch(this.handleErrorObservable); 
 }

//delete service

 del_role(id:number){
 var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Token ' + 
 localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));
 var options =  {
 headers: headers
 };

 return this.httpClient.delete('api/auth/role/' + id, options)
 .map((response: Response) => < any > response.json())
 .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);  
 }
```

> **component.ts**

```
//add operation

addRole(role){
console.log(role.value);
this.Authentication.sendRole({'name':role})
.subscribe(role=> this.persons =role)
}

//delete operation

deleterole(id){
this.Authentication.del_role(id).subscribe(res =>{
console.log('deleted successfully');
},
err =>{
console.log('error occured');
})
}
```

//***create error***
   [image: error when creating]

//***delete error***
   [image: error while deleting]

Comment: If you're using httpClient NOT use res.json

Comment: if i do that then its showing   Error: trying to diff 'value' Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Answer (score 0):

Try it,this will work for you. for httpClient we don't need add .map,by default httpclient will return result as a json formate, if we want total responce of httpclient request in that case we need to give option as ==> observe: 'response'.

```
//create service

 sendRole(data){
 console.log(data);
 let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
 }).set('Authorization', 'Token ' + 
 localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));


 return this.httpClient.post('api/auth/role/', data, {
        headers: headers ,
        observe: 'response'
    })
 }

//delete service

 del_role(id:number){
 var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Token ' + 
 localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));

 return this.httpClient.delete('api/auth/role/' + id, {
        headers: headers ,
        observe: 'response'
    })
};
```

component.ts

```
 //add operation

    addRole(role){
    console.log(role.value);
    this.Authentication.sendRole({'name':role})
    .subscribe(result=> this.persons =result.body)
    }

    //delete operation

    deleterole(id){
    this.Authentication.del_role(id).subscribe(res =>{
    if(res..status == 200){
    console.log('deleted successfully');
}
    },
    )
    }
```